# Retrieving CheckBoxList Values in Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, function, controls

I have a **cblSchedule** *checkboxlist* in my .ascx page that allows selection of *Daily/Weekly*:

```
<div class="form-group" id="schedule">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblSchedule">Schedule</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:CheckboxList ID="cblSchedule" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chkLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onchange="ToggleSchedule(this)" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="Daily" Value="Daily"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Weekly" Value="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckboxList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a **chkSelectDay** *checkboxlist* displayed when *Weekly* is checked:

```
<div class="form-group" id="divSelectDay" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblSelectDay">Select Day of Week</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSelectDay" CssClass="chkLabel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="Monday">Mon</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tuesday">Tue</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Wednesday">Wed</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Thursday">Thu</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Friday">Fri</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Saturday">Sat</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sunday">Sun</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a toggle function that display/hide **chkSelectDay** when *Weekly* is checked/unchecked in **cblSchedule** :

```
function ToggleSchedule(controlId) {
    var frmControl = document.getElementById(controlId.id);
    var divDay = document.getElementById("divSelectDay");

    var checkbox = frmControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked)
        {
            if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly")
                divDay.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly") {
                divDay.style.display = 'none';

            //UNCHECK ALL chkSelectDay checkboxes <--

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add in the functionality of unchecking all checkboxes in **chkSelectDay** when *Weekly* is unchecked in **cblSchedule**.

I tried to retrieve checkbox count via `$('#chkSelectDay')`.

But I was unable to use `.Count` nor `.Length`, so I can't use a `for-loop` to set `.Checked = false`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should know is by default `CheckBoxList` stores its value inside `ViewState` and not show it in client-side. You need to add `ClientValue` attribute inside `ListItem` to let checkboxlist values available in client-side:

```
<asp:CheckboxList ID="cblSchedule" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chkLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onchange="ToggleSchedule(this)" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Daily" Value="Daily" ClientValue="Daily"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Weekly" Value="Weekly" ClientValue="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckboxList>
```

Then, handle `change` event to make sure that the `Weekly` value is passed, otherwise uncheck all of `chkSelectDay` checkboxes:

```
$("#cblSchedule input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).parent().attr('clientvalue');

    // check if the value is 'weekly'
    if (this.checked && value != "Weekly") {
        // set all day selection checkboxes to 'unchecked'
        $("[id*=chkSelectDay] input").removeAttr("checked");

        // hide day selection checkboxes
        $('#divSelectDay').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Related issues:

[Get the Checkboxlist value when unchecked Client-Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422445/get-the-checkboxlist-value-when-unchecked-client-side)

[Check uncheck all CheckBoxes on the basis of another CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663496/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-on-the-basis-of-another-checkbox)

[ASP.Net CheckBoxList: Check or uncheck all checkboxes client side using jQuery](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/ASP.Net-CheckBoxList-Check-or-uncheck-all-checkboxes-client-side-using-jQuery.aspx)